# Changing Scopes_Supported in the Discovery Endpoint

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I was wondering how I could change the discovery point metadata:

```
"scopes_supported": [
"openid"
```

],
to include "email" and "profile"
This metadata is found at the https://domain/name.onmicrosoft.com/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration?p={policy-name}

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just confirmed with Azure support engineer that we can not modify the scope in the metadata.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the info! So that means an openid custom policy can never have an email scope? I can't change anything to a policy to make this happen?

Comment: @AlexFAHM Though the metadata can not be edited, you can add the email scope in the authorize endpoint manually. scope=openid%20email

Comment: @AlexFAHM Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Comment: @TonyJu Where do you add that code sample you provided?